# Interactive elements of a web page

Tags: sitemap, information-architecture

I was wondering if we have to consider interactive elements of a web page which are basically changing a section of a web page as a new level when making a site map. For example, I have a web page "x" with edit, new, delete function button. Clicking on these buttons changes only a specific part of the page which is associated which is a constant area in itself. The parts of the web pages which don't change are the top navigation, footer etc. While thinking of a site map I wasn't sure if clicking on features like edit would be considered a new level since the web page is the same.

Comment: Yeah I m sorry if I wasn't being very clear. I am not sure if interactive parts of a web page as explained above count as another level or layer while creating a site map.

Comment: isn't that entirely up to you?

Comment: Yes design wise it's upto me. Personally I am of the opinion if a page is showing a bread crumb trail of it's previous page then we start saying we are going levels deeper, however functions like edit, delete, new are not really involving the users to be aware about their action, it's the steps a user has to do while doing the edit flow which will count as a deeper level in the flow.Was trying to see if there is a common definition  used for level in site map. Sorry its hard to explain without actual mockups or reference.

Answer (score 0):

No, interactive page elements would not be considered part of a site map.

The page they reside on would be placed on the site map, but that is it.

A site map is meant to record the hierarchy and individual pages of a site... the things a person can navigate to.

Interactive elements would not fit this *unless* there are several different bits on one page and those bits can be reached by anchors.